# I can not insert and get data to firebase real-time database when I am trying to write and read data to firebase database. Error showing like this

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase-realtime-database

This code I wrote for post method:

```
storeRecipes() { 
  const recipes = this.recipeService.getRecipes(); 
  this.http
    .put( 'ng-course-recipe-book-a84eb-default-rtdb.europe-west1.firebased…', recipes ) 
    .subscribe(response => { console.log(response); }); 
}
```

Refused to apply style from 'https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.

Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://ng-course-recipe-book-a84eb-default-rtdb.europe-west1.firebasedatabase.app/?auth= '' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: It does not have HTTP ok status.

core.js:4002 ERROR
HttpErrorResponse {headers: HttpHeaders, status: 0, statusText: 'Unknown Error', url: 'https://ng-course-recipe-book-a84eb-default-rtdb.europe-west1.firebasedatabase.app/', ok: false, …}
error: ProgressEvent {isTrusted: true, lengthComputable: false, loaded: 0, total: 0, type: 'error', …}
headers: HttpHeaders {normalizedNames: Map(0), lazyUpdate: null, headers: Map(0)}
message: "Http failure response for https://ng-course-recipe-book-a84eb-default-rtdb.europe-west1.firebasedatabase.app/: 0 Unknown Error"
name: "HttpErrorResponse"
ok: false
status: 0
statusText: "Unknown Error"
url: "https://ng-course-recipe-book-a84eb-default-rtdb.europe-west1.firebasedatabase.app/"
[[Prototype]]: HttpResponseBase

Comment: Hello Sanjar Have you edit the rules in firebase ? If not then please edit the rules may be It will solve your problem

Comment: Thanks Kiran, I changed rules to true in firebase but it did not work. Still showing the same error

Comment: storeRecipes() {
    const recipes = this.recipeService.getRecipes();
    this.http
      .put(
        'https://ng-course-recipe-book-a84eb-default-rtdb.europe-west1.firebasedatabase.app/',
        recipes
      )
      .subscribe(response => {
        console.log(response);
      });
  }
 this code I wrote for post method

Comment: have you read the provided document [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/start)